How to use bigquery's .INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS in DBT source
in bigquery I have written something like this
FROM `my_project.my_dataset`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE 1 = 1
            AND table_name = 'tableA'

Question: how do I turn this FROM statement to DBT {{source("")}} format ?
I tried several ways to edit the source.yml file but i did not find the correct way yet
Thanks

you have a dbt package that handles all that: https://github.com/bqbooster/dbt-bigquery-monitoring . Might be worth giving it a look

This one works for me:
profiles.yml
bigquery:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: bigquery
      method: oauth
      project: my_project
      dataset: my_dataset
      threads: 4

sources.yml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: info_schema
    schema: INFORMATION_SCHEMA
    database: my_dataset
    tables:
      - name: COLUMNS

model.sql
SELECT * FROM {{ source('info_schema', 'COLUMNS') }}

